Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity Deprecated Version Problem
Since the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity is deprecated, I have tried to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore but i have a problem with using SignInManager in my Application layer. This is the exact code with .csproj file. I can see UserManager because Identity.EntityFrameworkCore package uses Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core package but in this Extensions package there is no SignInManager.
Actual code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

public UserManagementService(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}

.csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Mapster" Version="6.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.28" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.28" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Forum.Domain\Forum.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Forum.Persistence\Forum.Persistence.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

What can I do to achieve this functionality.
I have tried to move this functionality in API layer and it worked. There is no such thing as Asp.NetCore.Identity in API but somehow it uses 6.0.0 version of this package which is not available in package manager.

UserManager exists because it targets netstandard. Signinmanager is tightly coupled with asp.net, cookies, http, etc. so it is not suitable for class libraries. So due to design reasons your class library needs to target both .NET Core 6.0 and needs a FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App: <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />. Here is an example you can use as a reference:
Before adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package:

After adding:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

       <PropertyGroup>
             <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
             <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
             <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
       </PropertyGroup>

       <ItemGroup>
             <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
             <PackageReference Include="Mapster" Version="6.5.1" />
             <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.28" />
             <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.28" />
       </ItemGroup>

       
</Project>


